# Explain Max in this query

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregation

So, what is the usage of MAX here for pivoting table, without it, the query won't work.

```
SELECT
  item_id,
  MAX(IF(property_name = 'color', value, NULL)) AS color,
  MAX(IF(property_name = 'size', value, NULL)) AS size,
  MAX(IF(property_name = 'weight', value, NULL)) AS weight
FROM
  properties
GROUP BY
  item_id
```

Comment: It gets you the alphabetically last color, size, and weight for each item (assuming `value` is a string data type).

Answer (score 0):

the  use of aggregation function allow to reduce the number of rows compacting the result for each values in a single (fake) aggregated  rows

You could also use min  or others  aggregation function  the use of the function is just for reduce several rows to one and obtain the pivot result

```
SELECT
  item_id,
  MIN(IF(property_name = 'color', value, NULL)) AS color,
  MIN(IF(property_name = 'size', value, NULL)) AS size,
  MIN(IF(property_name = 'weight', value, NULL)) AS weight
FROM
  properties
GROUP BY
  item_id
```